# What is the name of this unusual C++ template feature used by Boost.Spirit?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, language-lawyer, boost-spirit

The code below is from the [Boost.Spirit x3 documentation](http://ciere.com/cppnow15/x3_docs/spirit/tutorials/roman_numerals.html#spirit.tutorials.roman_numerals.grammars). It uses an interesting C++ syntax that I've never seen before, which is nearly impossible to describe in a search query without knowing the proper terminology. Is this shorthand for the forward declaration of a class? Where is this feature mentioned in the C++ standard?

```
namespace parser
{
    using x3::eps;
    using x3::lit;
    using x3::_val;
    using x3::_attr;
    using ascii::char_;

    auto set_zero = [&](auto& ctx){ _val(ctx) = 0; };
    auto add1000 = [&](auto& ctx){ _val(ctx) += 1000; };
    auto add = [&](auto& ctx){ _val(ctx) += _attr(ctx); };

    // What is this? This is the very first use of the identifier `roman`.
    x3::rule<class roman, unsigned> const roman = "roman";
    //       ^^^^^^^^^^^

    auto const roman_def =
        eps                 [set_zero]
        >>
        (
            -(+lit('M')     [add1000])
            >>  -hundreds   [add]
            >>  -tens       [add]
            >>  -ones       [add]
        )
    ;

    BOOST_SPIRIT_DEFINE(roman);
}
```

Comment: It may be to disambiguate the class name "roman" from the variable name "roman."

Comment: Maybe, but it's interesting that the class *doesn't even exist* at the point of the `rule` template instantiation. Maybe it's something that is resolved on the second phase of name lookup?

Comment: To ease your searching: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/elaborated_type_specifier

Comment: @BarrettAdair, That declares the class as well.

Comment: FWIW, this feature is really handy for tags: `using MyType = TaggedThing<struct UniqueTag>;` The tag is useful for making each one a new type, and this is useful for making that type alias one line. Putting `struct` there is my personal preference - it could be `class`, `union`, `enum`, or `enum class` (and variants) AFAIK.

Comment: Fascinating. I cannot imagine how painful it must be to write a C++ parser. Thank you all!

Comment: There is also a section on elaborated type specifiers here: http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/c%2b%2b/4891/keywords/18504/class#t=201608310036584124696

Comment: As a side note, if you ever want to compile or debug your code, don't use Boost.Spirit.

Comment: "nearly impossible to describe in a search query without knowing the proper terminology" One of the greatest annoyances of life.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

The arguments to a template do not necessarily have to be defined to be used.  The use of "class roman" actually declares the class roman.

Here is some example code:

```
#include <iostream>
template <class T> void foo();
template<> void foo<class roman>()
{
    // allowed because roman is declared
    roman* pointer1;
    // not allowed because romania is not declared
    // romania* pointer2;
    std::cout << "Hello world!" << std::endl;
    return;
}
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    return 0;
}
```

As people have pointed out in the comments above, this distinguishes this instantiation of the template. And to directly answer the question you had, specifying the nature of the template argument in a template instantiation is called an 'elaborated type specifier'.

Comment: Thank you Robert for the elucidating example. I found my way to the relevant C++ standard sections from the comment from @chris above. In C++11, this is described in ISO/IEC 14882:2011.

Answer (score 27):

It is the same as:

```
class roman;

x3::rule<roman, unsigned> const roman = "roman";
```

In other words, writing `class T` where a typename is expected, first declares that `T` is the name of a class, and then proceeds with `T` as the typename being used for the rest of the expression.

Note that in C++ there is no clash between the typename `roman` and the variable name `roman` being declared here; that is allowed.

---

Another case of this can happen without templates, e.g.:

```
void func( class bar *ptr );
```

is correct if `bar` is undeclared; it declares `bar` and then declares the function to take a pointer to `bar`.